# execute local script on remote host as root, doesn't let you enter password

Tags: ssh, sh, sudo, aix

I am attempting to run a local script on a remote AIX server as root, but it doesn't pause to let me enter the sudo password.

```
ssh -t user@host 'sudo su' < action.sh
user@host's password:
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Executing without passing in the script works fine.

```
$ ssh -t user@host 'sudo su'
user@host's password:
Password:
# whoami
root
#
```

action.sh just contains an 'ls -al' command for testing.

How can I get this to pause so I can enter my password?

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is straightforward :

`STDIN` is feeded by your script, so each lines is passed as a password from in the input file.

A solution is to use a pair of `ssh` keys. [Here is a how to to do it.](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)